# Get last word from URL after equals sign

Tags: php

I can't find a solution for this problem. I have this URL `http://examplesite.com/?skill-type=new`  and I want to get the very last word after the = sign, using PHP only. "skill-type" stays the same all the time Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is it always going to be Skill-Type at the end, or is that variable as well?

Comment: Like, you want the `GET` variable: `$_GET['skill-type']`?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? You research first, ask last. Try looking into `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you already have the URL in a variable, let's say

```
$url = 'http://examplesite.com/?skill-type=new;
```

One possible way (certainly there are others) would be:

```
$urlArray = explode('=',$url);
$last = $urlArray[sizeof($urlArray)-1];
```

Note:
only applicable if you don't know how the URL comes, if you do, consider on using $_GET

Comment: 10x U'r comment and the next 1 was what I needed :) Both worked great, were clear and easy to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

This snippet should do:

```
$url = 'http://examplesite.com/?skill-type=new';
$skillType = explode('&', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY))['skill-type'];
```

Check [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) for more details.

If you meant that the request comes in to that particular url, just use `$_REQUEST['skill-type']` to retrieve the value.

Comment: He didn't say that it was a request to this particular URL. Might be string.

Comment: His question was too vague then

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP $_GET Global Variable

```
$skill_type = $_GET['skill-type'];
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP will automatically parse `GET` variables for you. To access the value of the `skill-type` variable, you need only use `$_GET['skill-type']`. For instance:

```
echo $_GET['skill-type'];
```

Will display

```
new
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate your url by $_SERVER variable and then split it like this

```
$url = "http://examplesite.com/?skill-type=new";
$array = explode("=", $url);
$last_word = $array[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substr (url, posstr (url,'=')+1) or if this is the page being loaded $_GET ['skill-type']